# How to securely distribute serial keys?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

I'm selling my Windows application over my website. I'm using Paypal and LibertyReserve as my payment processors. I created checkout buttons to automate the purchase process. After the purchase is complete, the buyer is redirected to a thank you page.

I'm issuing a serial and a download link after the checkout is complete. I'm currently doing it by using PHP, but it's not secure.

I have a text file with some 100 serials in it. Every time the user visits the thank you page, PHP script checks if the cookie is not set (to avoid repeated visits). If the cookie is not set, it opens the text file with the serials, reads the first serial and stores it in a cookie. The serial is deleted from the text file. After that, user is redirected by using "header" to the final page where it shows the cookie content and says "This is your serial key: [cookie value containing the serial goes here]".

Now, everyone with a bit of brain can just read the whole text file with the serial keys. How can I secure this/make it better?

Any suggestion will come handy. Thanks!

Comment: Remember that a cookie can be created/removed/edited by user and program. Don't ever trust cookie information blind!

Answer (score 0):

Store every serial code in MySQL database, table could be like this:

```
id, serial, purchased, date, hashcode
```

When user comes back from paypal with success payment, you will redirect him to something like serial.php?hashcode={hashcode} script which retrieves serial number by hashcode and print it to user. Script will also set serial row as purchased and if you don't want to allow user to see this page second time you can do it.

Comment: I'm looking into MySQL now. I never used it so it's gonna take some time. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You have a table with all the serial keys.

```
+--------+-----------+
| id     | serial    |
+--------+-----------+
| 1      | 123-45    |
+--------+-----------+
| 2      | 456-43    |
+--------+-----------+
```

When a transaction is executed, and you have an unique identifier for the transaction, you would have another table that holds what serial id belongs to the unique identifier.

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| id     | trans     |  serialId |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 1      | 654326    |  1        |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| 2      | 876430    |  2        |
+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

The serialId/trans column are unique so no two transactions could ever have the same serial id.